# Product sequence & factorial assignment, not sure if a line of code is in the right place

Tags: c++, sequence, product

Working on an assignment requesting to calculate the value of 'y', if 'n' and 'x' are given, 
Assignment: [image]

Should the line:

```
    P=P*(F+i/2);
```

be inside the 'else{ }'?!

The code:

```
//Calculate the value of 'y';
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double y, P=1, F=1;
    int x, n, i, j;
    cout<<"The value of x=";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"The value of n=";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(i==2||i==3)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            for(j=1;j<=(2*i-1);j++)
            {
                F=F*j;
            }
        }
        P=P*(F+i/2);
    }
y=pow((2*x+3),3)+P;
cout<<"The result for the value of y="<<y<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @LuchianGrigore If you mean debugging, yes.

Comment: I mean are you getting the correct results?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: it cannot get the correct result, the algorithm implementation is wrong.

Comment: @AndyProwl so not getting the correct result should be the first sign that it's wrong, right?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: exaclty. which is why he's posting this as a question i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be inside the `else` clause, after the `for` cycle. Also, you have to reinitialize `F` to `1` every time before computing the factorial. I would rewrite it this way:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    if((i!=2) && (i!=3))
    {
        F = 1; // Don't forget this!
        for(j=1;j<=(2*i-1);j++)
        {
            F=F*j;
        }

        P=P*(F+i/2.0); // Don't forget the 2.0 (or you'll get integer division)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think at the 'if' it shouldn't be '&&' but '||' because the 'i' cannot be 2 and 3 at the same time! Or I'm wrong?!

Comment: no, I think it's correct the way I wrote it originally: if `i` is different from 2 *and* `i` is different from 3 (i.e. if `i` is neither 2 nor 3), then you want to do something; otherwise, you want to do nothing. am i mistaken?

Comment: there is one more issue, as another answer points out (i am going to edit mine): in `P=P*(F+i/2);` you are doing integer division of `i/2`, which gives you a rounded result. you probably don't want that. I am going to update that part of my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
P=P*(F+i/2); should be inside else
```

Answer (score 0):

The `P=P*(F+i/2)` should indeed be within the else branch.

But there are more issues:

- You need to reset `F` for each factorial calculation
- Within `P=P*(F+i/2)` you are doing an integer division of `i`, which gives an incorrect result when `i` is odd.

You can also simplify your loop by taking the calculation for `i == 1` out of it:

```
P=1.5; /* For i == 1 */
for(i=4;i<=n;i++)
{
    F=1.0;
    for(j=1;j<=(2*i-1);j++)
    {
        F=F*j;
    }
    P=P*(F+i/2.0);
}
```

This removes the special cases for `i==2` and `i==3`.